# SingleChildScrollView with Column as a child vs ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any performance difference between those? Which one is more idiomatic? Or when should I use which?

One plus of using `SingleChildScrollView` with `Column` child is properties of `Column` (`mainAxisAlignment` etc.).

UPDATE:

I do know about `Listview.builder`. I use it when I want to render a list that is not short. The question is just about using either `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` because not all contents fit in the current screen so need to be scrollable.

Comment: I would use Column for laying out a few different widget types. I would use a ListView when listing any number of repeating widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You will miss the following in case of Column

The ListView.builder constructor takes an IndexedWidgetBuilder, which builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

Read more at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Answer (score 1):

i have been in your situation before , i personally prefer ListView with build function , if you are building alot of children , if thats not the case and you have fixed amount of children SingleChildScrollView will be handy especially if its nested in other Scrollable Widgets.

if performance is the issue ListView builder function is still the best choice , since it lazily build its child widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use a `SingleChildScrollView` when you want your list/content to be scrollable when the screen size is to small or the content overflows. Otherwise, use a `ListView` / `ListView.builder`.

By default the `SingleChildScrollView` is not scrollable, but you can force it by setting `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

Comment: SingleChildScrollView  is scrollable if content goes beyond need

Comment: Yes that is what I meant